# VGAScreen does not work on the Cosmos

Tags: c#, cosmos

I have a VGAScreen of the cosmos (with it I can create operating systems with C #), and it does not work, a mixed colors appears and then VMware closes. I'm trying to use the size 640x480, and it does not work, it worked when the size was 320x200.
My code:

```
screen.SetGraphicsMode(VGAScreen.ScreenSize.Size640x480, 
VGAScreen.ColorDepth.BitDepth4);
screen.Clear(0);
```

The OS stop after this:
[image]
Note: I am using the cosmos for VS2013.
Sorry for my english. I speak portuguese.

Comment: what is the size of your screen setting for your VGAScreen sounds like a hardware issue vs a code issue.. have you tried your monitor settings first..?

Comment: @MethodMan I set it up the display,but not work too.

Answer (score 1):

only 320x200 works on that version of cosmos, you should update to a version that is not as old